# How can I tell the lowest required version number of a Perl module?

Tags: perl, module, version

I'm writing a Perl module and right now I'm including in `Makefile.PL` all of the dependencies. The only problem is I have all of the latest versions of the modules required, but I don't want to limit anyone who has early versions (and either can't update them or requires older versions for old code). Is there any way to find out what would be the lowest version usable with my module without downloading and testing all of the versions? Thanks!

Comment: Um... you want a way to test if your code works with older versions of the library without... testing against the older versions of the library?  How could that possible work?

Comment: If you know that a certain version is required, specify that one. If you don't, don't specify one. In both cases, a later version might actually be required. You can adjust the version as automated testing reports and/or bug reports come in if necessary.

Comment: @AndyRoss there could be a module that made running tests against different versions of modules easy. It seems like a common problem that people would maybe have solved.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not an automated way to tell.  You probably want to start with reading the Changelog for each module and seeing what changes have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of Dist::Zilla? It won't help you with the version problem... but it helps you with a lot of other stuff for creating, maintaining and releasing modules. As mentioned by others, the only way to know the versions working is write tests and test against them...

Comment: I recently pulled Dist::Zilla from my module Data::Abridge, because it was becoming a burden.  Potential contributors complained about it and it was tough to keep working on all my different development environments.